# js: manipulate multi-dimensional array by index value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I need a hand sorting a multidimensional array by the value of the first index. JS or jQuery solutions, please I tried a for loop but without success.

I'm looking to transform the bellow array

```
var pinData = [
  ['<h3>Venue Name 1</h3>', '<div class="left">Session Name 1,<br> Event Date1</div>'],
  ['<h3>Venue Name 2</h3>', '<div class="left">Session Name 2,<br> Event Date2</div>'],
  ['<h3>Venue Name 3</h3>', '<div class="left">Session Name 3,<br> Event Date3</div>'],
  ['<h3>Venue Name 4</h3>', '<div class="left">Session Name 4,<br> Event Date4</div>'],
  ['<h3>Venue Name 3</h3>', '<div class="left">Session Name 5,<br> Event Date5</div>'],
  ['<h3>Venue Name 6</h3>', '<div class="left">Session Name 6,<br> Event Date6</div>'],
  ['<h3>Venue Name 1</h3>', '<div class="left">Session Name 7,<br> Event Date7</div>'],
  ['<h3>Venue Name 3</h3>', '<div class="left">Session Name 8,<br> Event Date8</div>']
]
```

into this:

```
var pinData = [
  ['<h3>Venue Name 1</h3>', '<div class="left">Session Name 1,<br> Event Date1</div><div class="left">Session Name 7,<br> Event Date7</div>'],
  ['<h3>Venue Name 2</h3>', '<div class="left">Session Name 2,<br> Event Date2</div>'],
  ['<h3>Venue Name 3</h3>', '<div class="left">Session Name 3,<br> Event Date3</div><div class="left">Session Name 5,<br> Event Date5</div><div class="left">Session Name 8,<br> Event Date8</div>'],
  ['<h3>Venue Name 4</h3>', '<div class="left">Session Name 4,<br> Event Date4</div>'],
  ['<h3>Venue Name 3</h3>', '<div class="left">Session Name 3,<br> Event Date3</div><div class="left">Session Name 5,<br> Event Date5</div><div class="left">Session Name 8,<br> Event Date8</div>'],
  ['<h3>Venue Name 6</h3>', '<div class="left">Session Name 6,<br> Event Date6</div>'],
  ['<h3>Venue Name 1</h3>', '<div class="left">Session Name 1,<br> Event Date1</div><div class="left">Session Name 7,<br> Event Date7</div>'],
  ['<h3>Venue Name 3</h3>', '<div class="left">Session Name 3,<br> Event Date3</div><div class="left">Session Name 5,<br> Event Date5</div><div class="left">Session Name 8,<br> Event Date8</div>']
]
```

In this case `pinData[0][1] = pinData[6][1]`, so `pinData[0][1]` should became `pinData[0][1] + pinData[0][6]`

Venue name 3: `pinData[2][1] = pinData[4][1] = pinData[7][1]`, so `pinData[2][2]` should became `pinData[2][2] + pinData[4][2] + pinData[7][2]`

For each Venue name that appear more then once the data at index2 merges.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to sort it out with a for loop. Not sure if it's the fastest or better way to do it but it works.

First thing was to get the data into 2 diff arrays, one that holds the venue name, and the second with the events.

maping the first array and creating an array that was holding the index of the first appearance of the venue name in this array helped in creating the loop.

this is it:

```
var pinData = [
  '<h3>Venue Name 1</h3>', 
  '<h3>Venue Name 2</h3>',
  '<h3>Venue Name 3</h3>',
  '<h3>Venue Name 4</h3>',
  '<h3>Venue Name 3</h3>',
  '<h3>Venue Name 6</h3>',
  '<h3>Venue Name 1</h3>',
  '<h3>Venue Name 3</h3>',
  '<h3>Venue Name 4</h3>'
]

var indexes = pinData.map(x => pinData.indexOf(x));
console.log(indexes);

var pinData2 = [
 '<div class="left">Session Name 1,<br> Event Date1</div>',
 '<div class="left">Session Name 2,<br> Event Date2</div>',
 '<div class="left">Session Name 3,<br> Event Date3</div>',
 '<div class="left">Session Name 4,<br> Event Date4</div>',
 '<div class="left">Session Name 5,<br> Event Date5</div>',
 '<div class="left">Session Name 6,<br> Event Date6</div>',
 '<div class="left">Session Name 7,<br> Event Date7</div>',
 '<div class="left">Session Name 8,<br> Event Date8</div>',
 '<div class="left">Session Name 9,<br> Event Date9</div>'
]

var results = [];


alert(pinData.length)
for(var i=0; i<pinData.length; i++){
  results[i] = pinData[i];
  for(var j=0; j<pinData.length; j++){
        if( indexes[j] == indexes[i] ){
        results[i] += pinData2[j]
    }
  }
}

console.log(results);


var containerEl = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0];
//containerEl.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(results);
containerEl.innerHTML = indexes;

var containerEl = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[1];
//containerEl.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(results);
containerEl.innerHTML = results;
```

here goes a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4apb0x39/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If *order does not matter*, you could switch this to an object, with the key being the `[0]` items:

```
var pinData = {
  '<h3>Venue Name 1</h3>': '<div class="left">Session Name 1,<br> Event Date1</div><div class="left">Session Name 7,<br> Event Date7</div>'
}
```

Then you can check if the object has a key:

```
if (pinData['<h3>Venue Name 1</h3>']) {
```

If it does, append your new data to that key:

```
pinData['<h3>Venue Name 1</h3>'] += ...
```

Otherwise, you can set the value:

```
pinData['<h3>Venue Name 1</h3>'] = ...
```

Again, remember that objects are by definition *unordered*.

Answer (score 0):

Taking an unsorted array, you may want to first sort it, then group it. Here's one way:

```js
// Data set we'll be working with
var pinData = [
  ['<h3>Venue Name 1</h3>', '<div class="left">Session Name 1,<br> Event Date1</div>'],
  ['<h3>Venue Name 2</h3>', '<div class="left">Session Name 2,<br> Event Date2</div>'],
  ['<h3>Venue Name 3</h3>', '<div class="left">Session Name 3,<br> Event Date3</div>'],
  ['<h3>Venue Name 4</h3>', '<div class="left">Session Name 4,<br> Event Date4</div>'],
  ['<h3>Venue Name 3</h3>', '<div class="left">Session Name 5,<br> Event Date5</div>'],
  ['<h3>Venue Name 6</h3>', '<div class="left">Session Name 6,<br> Event Date6</div>'],
  ['<h3>Venue Name 1</h3>', '<div class="left">Session Name 7,<br> Event Date7</div>'],
  ['<h3>Venue Name 3</h3>', '<div class="left">Session Name 8,<br> Event Date8</div>']
]

// Generic function to create a series of objects
//   The object key is the venue, and the event
//   is being pushed on if it matches the current
//   group venue.
var groupBy = function(xs, key) {
  return xs.reduce(function(rv, x) {
    (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x[1]);
    return rv;
  }, {});
};

// Here's where we actually start working.
//
// First, we want to sort the array by index.
var sortedArray = pinData.sort(function(a, b){
  return(a[0] > b[0]);
})

// Now, with the sorted array, we'll create
//  another array, with matching els combined.
var groupedArray = groupBy(sortedArray, 0);

// Simply a code dump, do with it what you will.
var containerEl = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0];

containerEl.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(groupedArray, null, 2);
```

```html
<div class="container">

</div>
```

Comment: almost there; unfortunately this alter the length of the array. I need the sorted array to have the same length and the sortedArr[i][0] to be = with pinData[i][0]. Cheers